# Python RSA Decryption Using OpenSSL Generated Keys

Tags: python, openssl, rsa, encryption

Does anyone know the simplest way to import an OpenSSL RSA private/public key (using a  passphrase) with a Python library and use it to decrypt a message.

I've taken a look at ezPyCrypto, but can't seem to get it to recognise an OpenSSL RSA key, I've tried importing a key with importKey as follows:

```
key.importKey(myKey, passphrase='PASSPHRASE')
```

myKey in my case is an OpenSSL RSA public/private keypair represented as a string.

This balks with:

> unbound method importKey() must be called with key instance as first
>   argument (got str instance instead)

The API doc says:

> importKey(self, keystring, **kwds)

Can somebody suggest how I read a key in using ezPyCrypto?  I've also tried:

```
key(key, passphrase='PASSPHRASE')
```

but this balks with:

> ezPyCrypto.CryptoKeyError: Attempted
>   to import invalid key, or passphrase
>   is bad

Link to docs here:

http://www.freenet.org.nz/ezPyCrypto/detail/index.html

**EDIT:** Just an update on this.  Successfully imported an RSA key, but had real problem decrypting because eqPyCrypto doesn't support the AES block cipher.  Just so that people know.  I successfully managed to do what I wanted using ncrypt (http://tachyon.in/ncrypt/).  I had some compilation issues with M2Crypto because of SWIG  and OpenSSL compilation problems, *despite* having versions installed that exceeded the minimum requirements.  It would seem that the Python encryption/decryption frameworks are a bit of a minefield at the moment.  Ho hum, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first error is telling you that `importKey` needs to be called on an *instance* of `key`.

```
k = key()
k.importKey(myKey, passphrase='PASSPHRASE')
```

However, the documentation seems to suggest that this is a better way of doing what you want:

```
k = key(keyobj=myKey, passphrase='PASSPHRASE')
```

Comment: Ok cool, that solves the import of my key.  
As for the decryption part I assume I use k.decString(someString) to decrypt the key... thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear what are you trying to achieve, but you could give M2Crypto a try. From my point of view it is the best OpenSSL wrapper available for Python.

Here is a sample RSA encryption/decription code:

```
import M2Crypto as m2c
import textwrap
key = m2c.RSA.load_key('key.pem', lambda prompt: 'mypassword')

# encrypt something:
data = 'testing 123'
encrypted = key.public_encrypt(data, m2c.RSA.pkcs1_padding)
print "Encrypted data:"
print "\n".join(textwrap.wrap(' '.join(['%02x' % ord(b) for b in encrypted ])))

# and now decrypt it:
decrypted = key.private_decrypt(encrypted, m2c.RSA.pkcs1_padding)
print "Decrypted data:"
print decrypted
print data == decrypted
```

Comment: It's very clear what I'm trying to achieve: "import an OpenSSL RSA private/public key (using a passphrase) with a Python library and use it to decrypt a message."

Comment: Well, example above does exactly that. 

However plain RSA encryption is rarely used on its own; usually you have some symmetric key encryption algorithm used to encrypt the data stream, and RSA used to encrypt the symmetric key. So may be you should describe your bigger problem if you want to find the best solution.